# i am trying to display the text of UI on label,what seems to be the issue?

Tags: ios, swift, string-interpolation

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var manu_label: UILabel!

    @IBAction func buttonpresses(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let title=sender.title(for:[])
        manu_label.text="you clicked \(title)) button"

    }
}
```

Whenever I try to click the button it shows this text in simulator rather than the only text on UI button.

Comment: what exactly happened when you click the button?

Comment: Your question is not clear. What happens exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
 @IBAction func buttonAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
     if let buttonTitle = sender.title(for: .normal) {
         print(buttonTitle)
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the following line:

```
let title=sender.title(for:[])
```

to this:

```
let title=sender.title(for: UIControlState.normal)
```

Optionally, you can drop `UIControlState`, so your code would look like this:

```
import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var manu_label: UILabel!
    @IBAction func buttonpresses(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let title=sender.title(for: .normal)
        manu_label.text="you clicked \(title)) button"
    }
}
```

Because you want to get the title of the button for the `UIControlState.normal`, and giving an empty array won't have the desired results.